# Is there a way to access data from another table during table.read - Azure Mobile App

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to get data from another database before reading data in the table. However, I can't seem to find a way to access it properly.

The best I've got so far is based on some other examples both on Microsoft's documentation and on StackOverflow but they all seem to fail.

```
table.read(function (context) {
    var results = context.tables("table2").read();

    var text = results[0].column;

    context.query.where({ columnName: text });

    return context.execute();
});
```

I get an error when doing this saying that column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description, if I do not misunderstand, you want to query table2 in table1 operations in EasyTables scripts.

we can leverage `"use()"` to custom **middleware** to specify **middleware** to be executed for every request against the table as the description on the document of azure-mobile-apps sdk at

E.G.

```
var queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query');
var insertMiddleware = function(req,res,next){
    var table = req.azureMobile.tables('table2'),
    query = queries.create('table2')
            .where({ TestProperty : req.body.testproperty });
    table.read(query).then(function(results) {
        if(results){
            req.someStoreData = somehander(results); //some hander operations here to get what you want to store and will use in next step
            next();
        }else{
            res.send("no data");
        }
    });
};

table.insert.use(insertMiddleware, table.operation);
table.insert(function (context) {
   console.log(context.req.someStoreData);
   return context.execute();
});
```

More example:

```
async function filterByAllowedDomain(context) {
  var domains = await context.tables('domains')
    .where({ allowed: true })
    .read();

  var categories = await context.tables('categories')
    .where(function (ids) {
        return this.domainId in ids;
    }, domains.map(d => d.id))
    .read();

  context.query.where(function (ids) {
    return this.categoryId in ids;
  }, categories.map(c => c.id));

  return context.execute(); }
```

The **`tables`** module in azure-mobile-apps-node sdk contains functionality for adding tables to an Azure Mobile App. It returns a router that can be attached to an express app with some additional functions for registering tables. Which actually leverage Azure SQL (SQL Server database service on Azure).

Hope it helps.